# Variables lose value swift

Tags: variables, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have an app that stores a players name and score inside the variables
"CurrentPlayer" and "CurrentPlayerScore". this works just fine. but when I switch to another view, which displays the name and their score (which works fine.), and then I switch back both my variables lose their value. any help is appreciated and i'm pretty new to swift so the clearer the better. thanks. (also I have used the prepare for segue method, which works for passing information to my next view controller but not back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global variables. There are defined in the global scope and can be accessed from everywhere in your project.

```
import UIKit

// globale Variablen
var global_address : String = ""
var global_username  : String = ""
var global_password  : String = ""
// globale Variablen

class ViewController
{
   // ....
}
```